# Quick topology question

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I confused myself. It is a seemingly trivial question:

If $U,V,B$ are sets in a topological space $X$ and $U \subset B$ is open in $B$ and $U = U \cap V$ is it true that $U \cap V$ is open in $B \cap V$?

I thought that yes but now I'm not sure. I tried to prove it and couldn't finish the proof as I seem to need $V$ open in $X$. Then I tried to find a counter example (in $\mathbb R$) but failed also.

Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$U\subset B$ open in $B$ means that $U=B\cap W$ where $W\subset X$
is open in the original topology on $X$.

Then likewise $\left(B\cap V\right)\cap W$ will be open in $B\cap V$
and this with $\left(B\cap V\right)\cap W=U\cap V$.

So indeed: $U\cap V$ is open in $B\cap V$.

You do not need $U=U\cap V$ for this.